# How to auto-activate cocoa window so you don't need to click twice?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I have two windows: A main window and an inspector panel. Both have sliders and draggable items.

You have to click twice every time you work in the other window. First click activates the window. Second click allows a drag to start.

Is it possible to have a click in a window automatically activate it AND allow the event to pass through to the controls so you don't need to do it twice all the time when switching between an inspector panel and main window?

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to try is to set the panel's `becomesKeyOnlyIfNeeded` property to true. That way, you main window will remain key even if the user clicks and drags on controls within the panel.

Otherwise, you have to handle this in each different view class. A view should override `-acceptsFirstMouse:` to return true if it wants to handle the same mouse event that activates the window. For custom view classes, this is straightforward. If you're using standard controls and they don't already implement `-acceptsFirstMouse:` to return true, you'll need to subclass them and use those subclasses instead.

Comment: Regarding your statement that you'll need to subclass standard controls:  The docs on `acceptsFirstMouse:` say that some controls such as `NSButton` and `NSSlider` already accept the first click.